# pass variable from codeigniter view to the external core php page

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can i pass variable from codeigniter view to the external core php page which is included in that view ?

For example,
 codeigniter view name is "login" and i have included a external php file name "logininner.php" and i want to pass a variable from "login" to "logininner.php".

can any one tell me a way to do this?

Comment: ya sure.. i have added <?php include(base_url()); ?> in my codeigniter view and in config.php i have assign $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sms11/jkblank/logininner.php';               my codeigniter view path is var/www/sms11/ and logininner.php path is var/www/jkblank/logininner.php  , now i have included that logininner.php in codeigniter view using base_url(); and my requirement is that i have to pass one variable from codeiginiter view to that logininner.php.. i hope that u r understand what i am trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can call `$this->load->view();` just like you would in a controller function. So in your view, you can do something like this

```
<?php $this->load->view('logininner', array('variable1' => 'value')); ?>
```

Then, in `logininner.php` you'll have `$variable1` set to the string `value`.

Comment: but logininner.php is not in inside my codeigniter application, it is included from another folder outside codeigniter app..

Comment: Where is it relative to your webroot? You can always use `../` to go up a directory...

Comment: ya sure.. i have added <?php include(base_url()); ?> in my codeigniter view and in config.php i have assign $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/sms11/jkblank/logininner.php';               my codeigniter view path is var/www/sms11/ and logininner.php path is var/www/jkblank/logininner.php  , now i have included that logininner.php in codeigniter view using base_url(); and my requirement is that i have to pass one variable from codeiginiter view to that logininner.php.. i hope that u r understand what i am trying to do?

Comment: @Ekansh No, don't set your base url to that file. That's just wrong, and you don't need to mess around with `base_url()`. Have you tried something like this? `<?php $this->load->view('../../../jkblank/logininner.php'); ?>`. Using `../` simply tells it to go up one directory. Also, have you tried using normal include in your views? It seems to me, that it'd be much easier and sufficient for your case.

Comment: yes i have tried both the ways and both are not working for me, so i have tried the $config['base_url'] way and this works properly. and now i found a way to pass that variable to logininner.php..till application is working properly..thanx for ur help :)